# Redirect a page from a button

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

Hi i'm trying to develop a login page using oracle **jdeveloper 12c** and. I'm working with **JEE** technology and JSF pages.

I want to redirect to the main page after pressing authentification button but it doesn't work and I get this excpetion:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: ADF_FACES-60101:Code de statut d''erreur HTTP : 404."

This is my authentification function in the ejb part

```
public String authentification(String login, String pwd) {
    try{
        Query query;
        query = em.createQuery("select o from UserEntity o where " 
                + " o.login = :LOGIN AND o.pwd = :PWD");

        query.setParameter("LOGIN",login);
        query.setParameter("PWD",pwd);
        query.getSingleResult();
        return  ("success") ;  
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }            
}
```

this is my loginaction in the managed bean

```
public String loginaction() {
    FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpServletRequest request =
    (HttpServletRequest)ctx.getExternalContext().getRequest();

    String Url =
    "/adfAuthentication?success_url=/faces/Main.jsf";

    HttpServletResponse response;
    response = (HttpServletResponse) ctx.getExternalContext().getResponse();

    RequestDispatcher dispatcher =
    request.getRequestDispatcher(Url);
    try {
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    } catch (IOException e) {
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Invalid Username or Password", "Invalid Username or Password");
           ctx.addMessage(null, msg);
    } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

ad this is my jsf

```
<af:panelFormLayout id="pfl1">
                        <af:inputText value="#{bindings.login.inputValue}" label="#{bindings.login.hints.label}"
                                      required="#{bindings.login.hints.mandatory}"
                                      columns="#{bindings.login.hints.displayWidth}"
                                      maximumLength="#{bindings.login.hints.precision}"
                                      shortDesc="#{bindings.login.hints.tooltip}" id="it1">
                            <f:validator binding="#{bindings.login.validator}"/>
                        </af:inputText>
                        <af:inputText value="#{bindings.pwd.inputValue}" label="#{bindings.pwd.hints.label}"
                                      required="#{bindings.pwd.hints.mandatory}"
                                      columns="#{bindings.pwd.hints.displayWidth}"
                                      maximumLength="#{bindings.pwd.hints.precision}"
                                      shortDesc="#{bindings.pwd.hints.tooltip}" id="it2">
                            <f:validator binding="#{bindings.pwd.validator}"/>
                        </af:inputText>
                        <af:button actionListener="#{bindings.authentification.execute}" text="authentification"
                                   disabled="#{!bindings.authentification.enabled}" id="b1"
                                   action="#{Login2.loginaction}"/>
                    </af:panelFormLayout>
```

this is what i get in the server dashboard

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: ADF_FACES-60101:Code de statut d''erreur HTTP : 404."
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.config.rich.XmlHttpServletResponse._logException(XmlHttpServletResponse.java:141)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.config.rich.XmlHttpServletResponse.sendError(XmlHttpServletResponse.java:107)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.config.rich.XmlHttpServletResponse.sendError(XmlHttpServletResponse.java:101)
at weblogic.servlet.FileServlet.findSource(FileServlet.java:267)
at weblogic.servlet.FileServlet.doGetHeadPost(FileServlet.java:178)
at weblogic.servlet.FileServlet.service(FileServlet.java:160)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:341)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:238)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:573)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:272)
at view.Login2.loginaction(Login2.java:54)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:254)
at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:302)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.MethodExpressionMethodBinding.invoke(MethodExpressionMethodBinding.java:46)
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXCommand.broadcast(UIXCommand.java:190)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._invokeApplication(LifecycleImpl.java:1083)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:402)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:225)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:341)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
at oracle.adf.model.servlet.ADFBindingFilter.doFilter(ADFBindingFilter.java:192)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:106)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:478)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:478)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:303)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:208)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:137)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:315)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:460)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:120)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:217)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:81)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:225)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3367)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3333)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2220)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2146)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2124)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1564)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:254)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:295)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:254)
```

Comment: Out of curiosity: did you get this code from some tutorial site? I know nothing about adf, but as a rule of thumb: directly mucking with request dispatchers should be avoided (*especially* in managed beans).

Comment: the redirection part from stackoverflow

Comment: As I said, no idea about adf, but since jdeveloper12c seems to support JEE6, you may have success with simply returning "Main" or "faces/Main" from the managed bean (instead of forwarding).

Answer (score 0):

From the log i see that it's not just a simple JSF , but an ADF based application. I can think of two ways to achieve the redirection to a page:

1. You could define a navigation rule in the adfc-config.xml (or even faces-config.xml) file and then, simply put the name of this defined rule as the button's action property value.
 2. If you wish a programmatically approach, then you could call a code returning this kind of string, `"mainPage.jsf?faces-redirect=true"` , since adf adds its own context. For example:

`public String loginaction() {
        ........
        return "mainPage.jsf" + "?faces-redirect=true";
    }`

NOTE: You might need to add "/faces/mainPage.jsf" or "/faces/.../mainPage.jsf" instead. It really depends on the location of the two pages participating in the navigation.
As per the dispatcher part, that was used with JSP. It is not needed nor advisable to use it anymore.

Comment: thank you i change it to
    public String loginaction() {

        BindingContainer bindings = getBindings();
            OperationBinding operationBinding = bindings.getOperationBinding("authentification");
            Object result = operationBinding.execute();
            if (!operationBinding.getErrors().isEmpty()) {
                return "/faces/Main.jsf?faces-redirect=true";
            }
            return "/faces/untitled1.jsf?faces-redirect=true";
        }
     
        but it always redirect to untitled1.jsf i don't know why, can you help me please?